# Passing ints into other activity causes strange behavior

Tags: java, android

I am passing 3 `ints` from `MainActivity` to `main` and displaying them in separate `Textviews`. When I click button to go to next activity, it shows the last passed `int` in the last textview. Pressing the back button on my smartphone, it resets the last textview to 0 and shows the correct value for the second textview. Then pressing the back button again, it resets the second textview to 0 and shows the correct value for the first textview.

Code inside `OnCreate` method at `MainActivity.java`:

```
            Intent sendX = new Intent(MainActivity.this, main.class);
            sendX.putExtra("x", x);
            startActivity(sendX);
            Intent sendY = new Intent(MainActivity.this, main.class);
            sendY.putExtra("y", y);
            startActivity(sendY);
            Intent sendZ = new Intent(MainActivity.this, main.class);
            sendZ.putExtra("z", z);
            startActivity(sendZ);
```

Code inside `OnCreate` method at `main.class`:

```
    Intent getX = getIntent();
    x = getX.getIntExtra("x", 0);
    Intent getY = getIntent();
    y = getY.getIntExtra("y", 0);
    Intent getZ = getIntent();
    z = getZ.getIntExtra("z", 0);

    TextView test1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.testx);
    test1.setText(Integer.toString(x));
    TextView test2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.testy);
    test2.setText(Integer.toString(y));
    TextView test3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.testz);
    test3.setText(Integer.toString(z));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to read up on how Intents work some more.  You're basically starting 3 instances of the same Activity.  Do this instead:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, main.class);
intent.putExtra("x", x);
intent.putExtra("y", y);
intent.putExtra("z", z);
startActivity(intent);
```

and

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
x = intent.getIntExtra("x", 0);
y = intent.getIntExtra("y", 0);
x = intent.getIntExtra("z", 0);
```